# How to set or get a button background image (and or even button image)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Play button` on my winform called `btnplay`. I set its background image by an image(play.png). I want when clicked `btnplay` its background image changed to another image (pause.png). I write this Conditional code but it don't work!

```
string customPath = "../img/";
string playImageFilename = "play.png";
if (btnplay.BackgroundImage == Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(customPath, playImageFilename)))
        {...}
```

Comment: Or the code you pasted here is very incomplete to depict your real code or you area making a big mess. `==` doesn't assign values; for such purpose there is `=`

Comment: @sergiol although is not very clear, i guess that OP really wants to compare values. He is trying to check if the background image is the play image. Of course,that won't work

Comment: @LP. Gonçalves I put this code on click event. and yes i want to change the button play image to pause when i click, and also i want to change it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you using the Button `Tag` property for this. So, when you load the "play" background image, set the `Tag` property to "play", and when you change it to pause set the `Tag` to "pause"

So, on the button click event, you could do something like this:

```
string customPath = "../img/";
string playImageFilename = "play.png";
string pauseImageFilename = "pause.png";

if (btnplay.Tag.ToString() == "pause")
{
     btnplay.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(customPath, playImageFilename);
     btnplay.Tag= "play";
}
else
{
     btnplay.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(customPath, pauseImageFilename);
     btnplay.Tag= "pause";
}
```

Comment: I want to change the `BackgroundImage == Image.FromFile` to `BackgroundImage= Image.FromFile`, but edit queue is full :(

Comment: @sergiol ok done, you were right. Too quick typing i'm afraid :)

Comment: I didn't touch a C# compiler for years, and I didn't even used it to test your code now. But, by instinct I know `ToString` is a method, so it was missing `()`. By instinct also, I detected the `=` that should be `==`, because I am on C++ job, and it is a mistake easier to do in C++ than in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable outside of the `btnPlay` click event handler.

```
private bool playing = false;
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (playing)
   {
       // set play image
   }
   else
   {
      // set pause image
   }
   playing = !playing;
}
```